# Скрипт для кнопки textarea

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть такой код

```html
<textarea class="auto-grow-input" name="text" placeholder="Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение" data-placeholder="Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение" data-height="24" onkeyup="postComment(this.value,1012,31,event);">Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение</textarea>
```

Сейчас комментарий отправляется при нажатии на enter, ну на `textarea`, как сделать кнопку для этого `textarea` чтобы она отправляла через скрипт ? На странице много постов, он отправляет по айдишнику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виесто *id* можно назначить другой ярлык на textarea

```js
function postComment(value){
  console.log(value);
  console.log('Отправлено');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="message" class="auto-grow-input" name="text" placeholder="Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение" data-placeholder="Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение" data-height="24" onkeyup="postComment(this.value,1012,31,event);">Нажмите «Ввод», чтобы отправить сообщение</textarea>
<button onclick="postComment(message.value,1012,31,event);">Отправить</button>
```

Comment: а как он будет высчитывать какой с какого текстареа брать содержимое

Comment: @David Develop, тот у котогоро id="message"

Comment: понял надо для многих textarea

Comment: сколько там этих постов? думаю всеравно надо будет вешать какой-то якорь

Comment: да, их на странице очень много

Comment: бесконечная подгрузка ajax

Comment: динамически создаются при получении данных с ajax?

Comment: Да, второе значение это id поста

Comment: ну второе значение передаваемое через функцию

Comment: но textarea у вас же не 1000 штук?

Comment: Нет, но больше 50

Comment: так. а они динамически создаются или вручную в html?

Comment: Создаются динамический через переменные

Comment: можете пожалуйста скинуть в вопрос кусок скрипта где они создаются

Comment: или там через ajax?

Comment: там php, просто подставляется id статьи из бд берется

Comment: стоп чего я туплю. тогда просто создавайте так же динамически кнопки с 
    onclick="postComment(message.value,1012,31,event);"

но вместо "message" указываейте id который прилетел

Comment: @David Develop, сработало?

Comment: Да!) Только надо было создать отдельную функцию для этого